# Any idea how to implement a custom AuthenticationProvider for a Visual Studio Code extension?

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to implement custom OAuth (with refresh token) to an extension for Visual Studio Code but I'm having a hard time trying to understand how the AuthenticationProvider works and how a custom one needs to be implemented.

I know we have the https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/github-authentication example but still having trouble how something custom should be implemented.

For example `createSession` function should do the whole authentication process and return a session. But how would you trigger a browser redirect to the OAuth2 endpoint, then capture the callback, get the token, etc in same function? How would you do all these external actions inside this single function?

Anyone has a better understanding of how this is implemented inside VSC and how does it work?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Well actually it is well described under githubServer.ts